# How can I pull nested JSON values from python using dictionaries?

Tags: javascript, python, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My database is formatted like this:

```
{
  "latitude" : 41.884629,
  "longitude" : -87.648764,
  "name" : "Bar Siena",
  "placeID" : "ChIJf3h_t9osDogReehZO7Hgk50",
  "vibes" : {
    "LGpswrvLgfYppcBG4bpmNzXQVoU2" : {
      "rating" : 1,
      "timestamp" : 1.477961061358844E9
    },
    "OSzA2KhTBWS3pxVnCZ6eScAuNDG3" : {
      "rating" : 5,
      "timestamp" : 1.477955566836665E9
    }
  }
}
```

I want to pull both the names of each bar, and every rating corresponding to it in the vibes table. My code looks like this:

```
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

db = firebase.database()
for i in range(1,100):
    venues = db.child("venues").child(i).get()
    dict = (venues.val())
    print(dict['name'])
```

So far i'm only able to get the names, but i'm not sure how to go deeper and get the ratings. My database is managed using Firebase, and I'm using a python library called Pyrebase that's just a wrapper for the javascript api. I'm having trouble because each vibe has a generated hash key so i'm not sure how to go deeper. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you show the format of the output you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vibes` probably comes as a dictionary. What you want are the ratings of each hash key, so you can do something like

```
for hashkey, vibe_dict in dict['vibes'].items(): # dict is a Python keyword, so it's a bad choice for a variable!
    print(hashkey, vibe_dict['rating'])
```

Comment: this is what I ended up using and it worked, didn't realize python would automatically map the key. Thank you!

Comment: @AmeerAkashe Glad I could help! If possible, please mark the answer as selected so that future viewers of your question know it's resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about `firebase`, but in plain python you may do it like:

```
>>> for vibe in my_json['vibes'].values():
...     print vibe['rating']
...
1  # Rating of item 1
5  # Rating of item 2
```

where `my_json` is the `dict` build from your json:

```
{
   "latitude":41.884629,
   "longitude":-87.648764,
   "name":"Bar Siena",
   "placeID":"ChIJf3h_t9osDogReehZO7Hgk50",
   "vibes":{
      "LGpswrvLgfYppcBG4bpmNzXQVoU2":{
         "rating":1,
         "timestamp":1.477961061358844E9
      },
      "OSzA2KhTBWS3pxVnCZ6eScAuNDG3":{
         "rating":5,
         "timestamp":1.477955566836665E9
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `venues` variable is a JSON-like object as in example, you can use the standart `json` library to work with it:

```
import json
dict_data = json.loads(venues)
print dict_data['latitude']
```

Btw, it's a bad style of development - to overwrite built-in Python funuctions. In your example you're overwriting dict(dict is a default Python type-object)